# undefined built in functions in Zend Studio 13

Tags: php, development-environment, zend-studio

I have created PHP7 project in Zend Studio 13 and I get warnings like this `Call to undefined function 'dba_open'`. Why Zend Studio didnt recognize these functions?

```
dba_open
dba_close
dba_fetch
mhash
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend doesn't ship language support for all the extensions in Zend Studio.

The most efficient way of adding support for language entities provided by unsupported extensions is definitely creating stubs. 
The description "stub" files for all supported PHP entities can be found in this directory: 
/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.php.core/**language** 
And this is also the location where you should put your stub files.

Answer (score -1):

Copy PHP code from below. Create a file DBA.php and put it into a folder 
workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.php.core/__language__/languagecode/DBA.php

languagecode - 8 hex digit name

You won't be able to debug a code having those functions, but at least there will be no warnings anymore.

```
<?php

/**
dba_open() establishes a database instance for path with mode using handler.

@link http://php.net/manual/en/function.dba-open.php

@param path string <p>Commonly a regular path in your filesystem.</p>

@param mode string <p>It is r for read access, w for read/write access to an already existing database,
c for read/write access and database creation if it doesn't currently exist, and n for create,
truncate and read/write access. The database is created in BTree mode, other modes (like Hash or Queue)
are not supported.<br>
<strong>Note:</strong><br>
There can only be one writer for one database file. When you use dba on a web server and more than
one request requires write operations they can only be done one after another. Also read during write
is not allowed. The dba extension uses locks to prevent this.
</p>

@param handler string <p>The name of the handler which shall be used for accessing path. It is passed all
optional parameters given to dba_open() and can act on behalf of them.</p>

@return FALSE on failure or positive handle on success.
*/
function dba_open ( $path , $mode, $handler=null) {}

/**
 * dba_exists() checks whether the specified key exists in the database.
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.dba-exists.php
 *
 * @param string $key <p>The key the check is performed for.</p>
 * @param mixed $handle <p>The database handler, returned by dba_open() or dba_popen().</p>
 * @return Returns TRUE if the key exists, FALSE otherwise.
 */
function dba_exists ( $key , $handle ) {}

/**
 * dba_fetch() — Fetch data specified by key
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.dba-fetch.php
 *
 * @param string $key The key the data is specified by.
 * <p><div><h3>Note:</h3></div>
 * When working with inifiles this function accepts arrays as keys where index 0 is the group and index 1 is the value name. See: dba_key_split().
 * </p>
 * @param mixed $handle The database handler, returned by dba_open() or dba_popen().
 * @return Returns the associated string if the key/data pair is found, FALSE otherwise.
 */
function dba_fetch ( $key , $handle ) {}

/**
 * dba_fetch() — Fetch data specified by key
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.dba-fetch.php
 *
 * @param string $key The key the data is specified by.
 * <p><div><h3>Note:</h3></div>
 * When working with inifiles this function accepts arrays as keys where index 0 is the group and index 1 is the value name. See: dba_key_split().
 * </p>
 * @param $skip The number of key-value pairs to ignore when using cdb databases. This value is ignored for all other databases which do not support multiple keys with the same name.
 * @param mixed $handle The database handler, returned by dba_open() or dba_popen().
 * @return Returns the associated string if the key/data pair is found, FALSE otherwise.
 */
function dba_fetch ( $key , $skip , $handle ) {}

/**
 * dba_delete — Delete DBA entry specified by key
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.dba-delete.php
 *
 * @param mixed $key The key of the entry which is deleted.
 * @param mixed $handle The database handler, returned by dba_open() or dba_popen().
 * @return Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
 */
function dba_delete ( $key , $handle ) {}

/**
 * dba_replace — Replace or insert entry
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.dba-replace.php
 *
 * @param mixed $key The key of the entry to be replaced.
 * @param mixed $value The value to be replaced.
 * @param mixed $handle The database handler, returned by dba_open() or dba_popen().
 * @return Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
 */
function dba_replace ( $key , $value , $handle ) {}

/**
 * dba_insert() inserts the entry described with key and value into the database.
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.dba-insert.php
 *
 * @param string $key <p>The key of the entry to be inserted. If this key already exist in the database, this function will fail. Use dba_replace() if you need to replace an existent key.</p>
 * @param string $value <p>The value to be inserted.</p>
 * @param mixed $handle <p>The database handler, returned by dba_open() or dba_popen().</p>
 *
 * @return Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
 */
function dba_insert ( $key , $value , $handle ) {}

/**
 * dba_firstkey() returns the first key of the database and resets the internal key pointer. This permits a linear search through the whole database.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.dba-firstkey.php
 *
 * @param mixed $handle The database handler, returned by dba_open() or dba_popen().
 * @return Returns the key on success or FALSE on failure.
 */
function dba_firstkey ( $handle ) {}

/**
 * dba_nextkey() returns the next key of the database and advances the internal key pointer.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.dba-nextkey.php
 *
 * @param mixed $handle The database handler, returned by dba_open() or dba_popen().
 * @return Returns the key on success or FALSE on failure.
 */
function dba_nextkey ( $handle ) {}

/**
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.dba-close.php
 *
 * @param mixed $handle The database handler, returned by dba_open() or dba_popen().
 * @return No value is returned.
 */
function dba_close ( $handle ) {}
```